# How do you recursively zip up a directory using wxWidgets?

Tags: zip, wxwidgets

How do you recursively zip up a directory using wxWidgets?  I would like to place the resulting zip file right next to the target directory at the same level.  The only input is simply one char string which contains the path of the directory to be zipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably lots of ways to do this, but the most straightforward way might be to combine a [wxDirTraverser](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_dir_traverser.html) and a [wxZipOutputStream](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_zip_output_stream.html).  Basically cutting and pasting from the samples in the docs, the derived traverser class could look something like:

```
class wxDirZipper : public wxDirTraverser
{
    public:
        wxDirZipper(const wxString& zip_filename, const wxString& folder)
        {
            wxFileName folder_to_zip_filename(folder);
            folder_to_zip_filename.Normalize();
            m_folder=folder_to_zip_filename.GetFullPath();
            m_zip = new wxZipOutputStream(new wxFileOutputStream(zip_filename));
        }

        ~wxDirZipper()
        {
            delete m_zip;
        }

        wxDirTraverseResult OnFile(const wxString& filename) wxOVERRIDE
        {
            wxFileInputStream fis(filename);
            m_zip->PutNextEntry(Chop(filename));
            m_zip->Write(fis);
            return wxDIR_CONTINUE;
        }

        wxDirTraverseResult OnDir(const wxString& dirname) wxOVERRIDE
        {
            wxDir dir(dirname);

            if( !dir.HasFiles() && !dir.HasSubDirs() )
            {
                m_zip->PutNextDirEntry(Chop(dirname));
            }

            return wxDIR_CONTINUE;
        }

    private:
        wxString Chop(const wxString& filename) const
        {
            wxFileName fullpath(filename);
            fullpath.Normalize();
            wxString temp = fullpath.GetFullPath();
            temp.Replace(m_folder,wxEmptyString);

            return temp;
        }

        wxZipOutputStream* m_zip;
        wxString m_folder;
};
```

You would then call this with something like:

```
wxString folder_to_zip = <whatever>
wxString zip_filename = folder_to_zip+".zip";

wxDirZipper zipper( zip_filename, folder_to_zip );
wxDir dir(folder_to_zip);
dir.Traverse(zipper);
```

This is a basic implementation, and there's lots of room for improvement.  You could, for example check before overwriting the zip file or use [wxZipEntry](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_zip_entry.html) to set metadata for the entries.

Comment: This works very well, thank you.  One problem though.  Say my cwd is a/b/c/d  and underneath is e/f/g.  I want to create a zip file e.zip and place it right under d.  It should unzip to e/f/g.  What is happening though is that it is created in the right place, but it unzips to a/b/c/d/a/b/c/d/e/f/g.  Thankfully the second copies of a/b/c/d are otherwise empty except for the one directory necessary to continue the chain.  I hope this makes sense.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Should have said unzips to a/b/c/d/e/f/g and the zip file is under the real d (as it should be).  This chain of directories therefore starts under the real d.  The entire path is in the first comment which has timed out and I can't edit.  I really hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Avoiding that was the point of the 'temp.Replace(m_folder,wxEmptyString);' in the OnFile method.  I guess if the the folder parameter passed to wxDirZipper doesn't exactly match the first part of filename in that method, the replace will fail.  I guess if the replace fails, the method should then try to parse filename, remove all of the initial folders, and then reconstruct the remaining items as the name to use for the PutNextEntry method.

Comment: I made an edit to filter the names of folder and the filenames through a normalized wxFileName so that the replace should always succeed.  Does that help?

Comment: We were on the same wavelength.  The input path had some forward slashes and some back slashes so the Replace was failing.  I made them all back slashes and it works perfectly.  I'm going to try your normalize routine too, I'm sure it will work as well.  Thank you so much, this really helps me out.

Comment: For future readers, the final code above posted by New Pagodi works perfectly.

Comment: I just found out that empty subdirectories are not showing up in the .zip file.  I tried adding some of the OnFile code to the OnDir method but that brings about crashes.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks. @NewPagodi

Comment: I've modified the wxDirZipper class to check for empty folders.   It seems to work, but I've only tested it with 1 folder.

Comment: This works great thank you.  Also, in the constructur I'm using GetPath instead of GetFullPath so that it creates the top level directory in the zip file.  Thanks for all the help.